# Named semaphores instead of mutex - readers writers problem without multithreading

Tags: c, linux, concurrency, fork, semaphore

My goal is to solve Readers Writers[1] problem but using only **isolated processes**. One process is for reader one for the writer, I should use named semaphores, so that **it is possible to start subsequent reader and writers at any time** - also I **can't use shared memory** - pure synchronization.

More info:
Provide implementation of **2 programs implementing a reader and
a writer**, so that **it is possible to dynamically start new processes while complying with the restriction**s.
Pay attention to the properties of concurrent processing: **safety and liveness**.
Consider also whether you program is **deadlock free**.

EDIT: problem is separated to 3 files
File 1. Reader:

```
int main(){
    sem_t *mutex;
    sem_t *write;
    int count=0;
    mutex = sem_open("/mutex", O_CREAT, 0600, 1);
    write = sem_open("/write", O_CREAT, 0600, 1);

    do{
        sem_wait(mutex);
        count++;
        if (count==1){
            sem_wait(write);
        }
        sem_post(mutex);

        printf("Critical section in readers\n");

        sem_wait(mutex);
        count--;
        if(count==0)
            sem_post(write);
        sem_post(mutex); 


    }while(1);
}
```

File 2. Writer

```
int main(){

    sem_t  *write;
    write = sem_open("/write", O_CREAT, 0600, 1);

    do{
        sem_wait(write); 
        printf("Critical section in writer\n");
        sem_post(write);

    }while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

File 3. Deleting semaphores

```
int main(){

    sem_unlink("/mutex");
    sem_unlink("/write");

    printf("Semaphores deleted \n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Problem:**

- when I run `reader` or `writer` with gcc -pthread file_name.c I don't
  get any result, as If the code wasn't doing anything - the process is
  running, the cursor is blinking but nothing happens.

[1]: READERS and WRITERS : The reading room has capacity of n
readers. Readers come to the reading room, allocate a single place, and occupy it for some time, then leave. After some time they come again and the procedure repeats. The reading room is also used by writers. However, a writer can only work when the reading room is empty, i.e. there must be no other reader nor writer. The writer occupy the room for some time, then leaves, and comes back after a while

Comment: If you can't use neither shared memory nor threads: you could read/write to a file and use fork/exec to have processes instead of threads. Not sure you need 2 semaphores. Try to start only with 2 processes: 1 reader and 1 writer.

Comment: Describe the reader-write problem.

Comment: Are you sure the programs you need to write are responsible themselves for "dynamically start[ing] new processes"?  Given that you're writing separate programs for reader and writer, my expectation would be that starting readers and writers would be an external operation, not something managed by the programs themselves.  And that would considerably reduce the complexity of each program, and put the focus on the synchronization objects that seem intended to be the topic of the exercise.

Comment: And speaking of two programs, your code appears to implement *one* program with two functionalities, not two programs.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Could you be more specific on where should I separate the code and how to put focus on synchronization? I'm a total beginner and I admit I don't understand what you say

Comment: @andrew_the_coder, based on what little of the instructions you have presented, and in light of the fact that this exercise is apparently intended for inexperienced programmers, my interpretation is that you are intended to write one program that implements one reader, and another, separate program that implements one writer.  Two (at least) source files, two `main()` functions, and synchronization objects and functions suited to that.  Very approximately, your `reader()` and `writer()` might be converted to the `main`s, but really, not much of what you've presented serves such a design.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you were right, I separated programs but I still can't figure out how to dynamically run new processes (I edited the question)

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to solve Readers Writers problem but using only isolated processes. One process is for reader one for the writer, I should use named semaphores, so that it is possible to start subsequent reader and writers at any time - also I can't use shared memory - pure synchronization.

Judging from this limited description, you can probably solve this problem by using [named pipes](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html).

> I can't use shared memory

The code treats global variables `counter` and `cnt` as if they are shared between processes. They are not, each process gets a copy of those with the same value, the changes to these variables are not seen by other processes.

---

To use functions [`sem_wait` and `sem_post` link with linker option `-pthread`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html).

Comment: I would like to stick to the code I have, as it is simple ( I'm a total beginner). Could you show me what should I change?

Comment: it worked, thanks! Still I have one question: does the code does its job correctly (meet criteria and works stably)?

Comment: @andrew_the_coder I don't think the code does what you expect it to do, see my update. You may like to post what exactly the processes should do.

Comment: I updated the code. Now I have to figure out how to run them and after that how to dynamically create new processes. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

You mentioned that you have to use "isolated processes", but as far as I know threads are not processes. to create a new process you have to use fork().

Differnces as mentioned here ([full link with difference-table](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-process-and-thread)):

> **A process is an active program** i.e. a program that is under execution.
>   It is more than the program code as it includes the program counter,
>   process stack, registers, program code etc. Compared to this, the
>   program code is only the text section.
>
> **A thread is a lightweight process** that can be managed independently by
>   a scheduler. It improves the application performance using
>   parallelism. A thread shares information like data segment, code
>   segment, files etc. with its peer threads while it contains its own
>   registers, stack, counter etc.

in simple words - each process can have in it multiple threads ("lightweight processes").
[image]

I think you have to use fork() to create new Processes because of the word "Process" that you mentioned. also, you mentioned that you need 2 processes (one for the reader and one for the writer) so you have to fork() twice and manage these 2 processes. You can read about fork() [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html).

edit (semaphore implementation):

```
int initsem(key_t semkey, int initval)
{
    int status = 0, semid;
    union semun {/* should to be declared according to C standards */
        int val;
        struct semid_ds *stat;
        ushort *array;
    } ctl_arg;

    if ((semid = semget(semkey, 1, SEMPERM | IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL)) == -1) {
        if (errno == EEXIST)
            semid = semget(semkey, 1, 0);
    }
    else    {              /* if created */
        ctl_arg.val = initval;     /* set semaphore value to the initial value*/
        status = semctl(semid, 0, SETVAL, ctl_arg);
    }

    if (semid == -1 || status == -1) { /* failure */
        perror("initsem failed");
        return(-1);
    }
    else return semid;
}

int sem_wait(int semid)
{
    struct sembuf p_buf;
    p_buf.sem_num = 0;
    p_buf.sem_op = -1;
    p_buf.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;

    if (semop(semid, &p_buf, 1) == -1) {
        perror("p(semid) failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    else return 0;
}

int sem_post(int semid)
{
    struct sembuf v_buf;
    v_buf.sem_num = 0;
    v_buf.sem_op = 1;
    v_buf.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;

    if (semop(semid, &v_buf, 1) == -1) {
        perror("v(semid) failed");      exit(1);
    }
    else  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement fork, could you have a look at my code and tell me if I'm going it the right direction and what should I change - cause the code is broken :). Thanks

Comment: _lightweight process_ is obsolete confusing language. A _thread_ is a flow of control represented as _task_ scheduling entity. A _process_ is virtual address space with one or more threads. There are also kernel threads that run within kernel address space, i.e. kernel is a pseudo-process with no pid.

Comment: I don't see any `sem_init` fuction.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin That's the terminology in the books. Of course you are right but for a student or a beginner your answer is like chinese.

Comment: @benjamin I'd say _lightweight process_ is vague and Chinese, whereas thread and virtual address space are specific, precise and insightful. In that picture Process is state the threads share - address space, file descriptors, signals, etc..

Comment: @benjamin isn't sem_init() a initialization of semaphore created by sem_t ? I guess I should try  sem_t *s = sem_open("/test1", O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 0) ?

Comment: @andrew_the_coder you have to implement it. I'll add an implementation for you.